# Mapbox not opening in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox-android

I have the 2020.3.32f1 version of Unity and have tried to open Mapbox version 2.1.1 - the current one I am being told by the Mapbox website to download. It says I need Unity 2017 and higher so everything should be right, correct? Then why does it not load properly and I get the following errors:

Assets\GoogleARCore\SDK\Scripts\ARCoreBackgroundRenderer.cs(43,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ARBackgroundRenderer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\GoogleARCore\SDK\InstantPreview\Scripts\InstantPreviewManager.cs(32,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'SpatialTracking' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Assets\UnityARInterface\ARRemote\Scripts\ARRemoteEditorInterface.cs(40,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ARBackgroundRenderer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\UnityARInterface\Scripts\ARCoreInterface.cs(51,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ARBackgroundRenderer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\UnityARInterface\Scripts\ARKitInterface.cs(26,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ARBackgroundRenderer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

A polygon of Mesh 'cone' in Assets/Mapbox/Examples/2_AstronautGame/AstronautGame/Park/cone.FBX is self-intersecting and has been discarded.

Problem detected while importing the Prefab file: 'Assets/MapboxAR/Prefabs/AR.prefab'.
The file might be corrupt or have missing nested Prefabs. See details below.
Warnings:
Component at index 2 could not be loaded when loading game object 'ARCamera'. Removing it.

So yeah, no matter what I do, it won't load/open properly - the examples window from Mapbox doesn't open, nor does the Ampbox tab appear at the top of the Unity UI. It's really, really annoying, I can't even open the thing!!! I just need to get into it so I can start learning with the PocketDroid Go example if anyone knows that one... Please help it's been days and I am getting nowhere and it's literally step one: "open the package!" :(

Comment: Please format you error logs correctly as code. And make sure you include only relevant parts.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure what you mean? Those are the only things that I see - I import the Mapbox package, and those errors that I have posted appear. It is not lines of code that haven't worked, it's literally input error lines. As far as I am aware, all the error code is relevant, why would any of it not be? Did you read my post fully?

Comment: It's not about the content but about formatting the content in a way that it's easily readable. Please put the error logs into a code block.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure what you mean? There is no other way to format that content, it is literally copy and pasted. I also don't know what a code block is sorry. I'm new to this. Also, I have the answer now anyway, Unity changed the name of ARBackgroundRenderer to ARCamera in like 2019 or something but Mapbox have never updated their SDK, hence the errors.

Comment: Hey @Waypoint, @Maccesch simply wants you to use backticks to surround your debug log in your original message. A backtick is a symbol that looks like a reverse apostrophe, or the unshifted tilde key. `This is an example`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved - Unity changed the name of `ARBackgroundRenderer` to `ARCamera` in like 2019 or something but Mapbox have never updated their SDK, hence the errors. If you use the April 2018 version of Unity, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete AR related things that came with Mapbox such as ARCore,Kit Interface, GoogleARCore, etc folders from your Assets.

Comment: I found this to work on 2022 versions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using unity Unity 2017.1.0 instead of 2020.3.32f1? Their examples seem to be using that version of the editor.